# Colored text in FireMonkey application

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

Since FMX doesn't have an equivalent of TRichEdit, how can I output a differently colored text? I'm writing a console (as in a Quake-style console, to clarify) output visual control for my application, and I don't see any way to solve it, except to draw the text myself, complicated by many factors (like scrolling).

Comment: Ypu might consider using TMS Pack for FireMonkey which also contains RichEdit like component. http://www.fmxexpress.com/professional-rich-edit-component-for-delphi-xe7-firemonkey-on-android-ios-osx-and-windows/

Comment: Nah, I don't want to use paid components.

Comment: Then I'm afraid you will have to make one yourself becouse I don't know about any freeware component to offer similar functionlity.

Comment: You could use a console

Comment: @David Heffernan: if you meant write a console application, then it's not possible, because I need it for a GUI app.

Comment: GUI apps can have consoles too.

Comment: Well, I mostly meant inconveniences arisen from such solution, like copy-pasting and whatnot.

Comment: Whoa, what have I found! ms-help://embarcadero.rs_xe7/rad/Using_FireMonkey_Text_Layout_Features.html (Delphi help, it's in FMX.TextLayout.TTextLayout). But I don't really get how to use it. I can draw a string with one color on a TMemo, but I can't make it draw differently colored strings nor correctly wrap words inside the control. Maybe someone else can understand how to use it. I hope.

Comment: Ah, it doesn't work. At all. I've found a demo program on the Embarcadero repository, and it refuses to do anything other than the mentioned drawing of a single string using a single color. Even the help page I linked earlier, if one looks closely, shows (2d picture) no black text after a change in text attributes.

Comment: TTextLayout says nothing about being able to draw multiple strings with multiple colors in a memo control. It says you can control the attributes (font and color) of the text it affects. I don't know where you got the interpretation that it meant "works like a VCL.TRichEdit for multi-colored text in the same block", because it doesn't say any such thing. You can use it for drawing text all you want yourself to a `TCanvas`, though; you have to position the text yourself. Create a separate `TTextLayout`, assign the properties you want it to have, and call `RenderLayout` to draw it.

Comment: What? If I understand correctly,
    Layout.AddAttribute(TTextRange.Create(2,4),
      TTextAttribute.Create(Layout.Font,claCoral));
should make characters from 3 to 5 of color "coral". Combining with different ranges and colors I should be able to get multicolored text easily. The help example implies so. And I don't get your fuss about drawing on a TMemo Canvas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now after thinking about it, since TTextLayout doesn't work as intended, I think that it can be done by creating an array of colored as needed TLabels in a TFlowLayout, but there are some things to consider: performance and memory usage, copy-pasting and word wrap. When I add a string to log, split it into strings so each string is of one color and for each string create a TLabel with text and color set accordingly.